# Angular - How to subscribe the same service responses with different parameters (multiple API calls)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rest, web-services

Below are my code snippets

**Angular service**

```
export class CarService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  // -------------------------------------------------
  // define observable Subject(s) which will be subscribed by callers
  private observableList = new Subject<CarModel>();
  public getObservableList() {
    return this.observableList.asObservable();
  }
  // -------------------------------------------------

  // fetch required required data, then add into observable 
  public fetchCarInfo(carId: string) {
    // call service
    const url = '.../api/car/' + carId;
    this.httpClient
      .get<CarModel[]>(url)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.observableList.next(data);
        }
      );
  }
}
```

**Angular component**

```
export class ListPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  car1: CarModel[];
  car2: CarModel[];

  constructor(private carService: CarService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // 1. subscribe Observable Subject
    const carsSubscription = this.carService
      .getObservableList()
      .subscribe(serviceResult => {
        // Here we can use returned serviceResult
        // but our service will be called 2 times with 2 different parameters!

      });
  }


  // in my business, I need to call the same service 2 times with different parameters
  // The issue here, BOTH calls will refresh the same Observable
  // so i can not know the returned serviceResult is related to the first or second call?
  public coreBusiness(carId1: string, carId2 string) {   
    // 2. call service method by parameters to fetch/refresh Observable
    this.carService.fetchCarInfo(carId1);
    this.carService.fetchCarInfo(carId2);   
  }

}
```

The normal solution
To add into **Service** *2 Observables* and in **Component** *subscribe both*!
But I think this is not a clean solution to add multiple Observables in the service equivalent to the number of service calls with different parameters.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you subscribing in service and using subject? Simply return observable from `fetchCarInfo` and let the caller [i.e. component or some other service] subscribe to it. Any specific reason to do so?

Comment: @user2216584 subscribing in service give me the ability to **handle the unexpected errors in one place inside the service** then I can put in the observable object what I need in this case to notify the caller by error case by checking it before use data

Comment: To handle the errors you can use `catchError` operator in the observable pipeline. You should only subscribe only from the caller. Having `catchError` operator in the pipeline also provide catching the error at one place. I could see that the usage of the subject is not needed. The best thing with Observable is the power of **composition** by using various operators. Removing of `subject` and returning observable can make your question answered quite easily. The thing is that you are trying to deal with two observables [subject + api] which could easily be done using one observable.

Comment: the usage of the subject is not needed.
You should only subscribe only from the caller.

Comment: @A.R.F +1 also subscribing in service give me the ability to **prepare the data before passing it to the caller** also if **your service response requires another service call**, so subscribing in service is a good option

Comment: you can prepare data using `map` operator, you can combine many calls using `flatMap` operator, no need to subscribe inside service

Comment: @ahmednabil88 You should understand how various operators could be used to compose your final observable. You can still process your data even call some other apis in the observable operators chain with out subscribe. Subscription should only be done by the caller. Subscription in the service is just a bad design. It absolutely not needed. Go through this awesome video from ngconf 2019 - https://youtu.be/Z76QlSpYcck

Comment: Now, you decide to use this way, this is better that in `CarServcie` you have keep the `data` instead of the `Observable` at the calling `getObservableList()` method,
It does it `fetchCarInfo` method no need to the `subscribe` and multiple API calls.